# json_merge_preserve on a column of JSON data

Tags: mysql, json

[json_merge_preserve](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-preserve) takes two or more JSON documents and merges them into one. However the function definition seems to only accept a fixed number of arguments.

So if I have a table like:

`create table jsons (data longtext);`

Which has an arbitrary number of rows, how can I use `json_merge_preserve`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
CREATE TABLE test (json_val JSON)
SELECT '{ "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}' json_val UNION ALL
SELECT '{ "a": 4, "c": 5, "d": 6}'          UNION ALL
SELECT '{ "a": 7, "b": 8, "e": 9}'          ;
SELECT CAST(json_val AS CHAR) FROM test;
```

| CAST(json_val AS CHAR) |
| --- |
| {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3} |
| {"a": 4, "c": 5, "d": 6} |
| {"a": 7, "b": 8, "e": 9} |

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS (
  SELECT json_val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rn
  FROM test
),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT json_val, rn
  FROM cte1
  WHERE rn = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(cte2.json_val, cte1.json_val), cte1.rn
  FROM cte1
  JOIN cte2 ON cte1.rn = cte2.rn + 1
)
SELECT CAST(json_val AS CHAR)
FROM cte2
ORDER BY rn DESC LIMIT 1;
```

| CAST(json_val AS CHAR) |
| --- |
| {"a": [1, 4, 7], "b": [2, 8], "c": [3, 5], "d": 6, "e": 9} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/si9zdw_U)